# Running a Blf file in constant Loop for Emulation using CAPL

Tags: can-bus, capl, canalyzer

I want to run a .blf file using the Replay Block in CANalyzer . I want to run this file in a constant loop for emulation purpose. Is it possible using CAPL or can some one instruct me how to do this even without CAPL.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need CAPL to replay a log file in a loop.

1. Right click the Replay block
2. In the "General" tab, enable "**Repetitive output sending mode**"