# How do I replay a .blf file in CANoe in real-time?

Tags: canoe, canalyzer

I found several questions on the subject here on SO, so I figured out this could fit as well.

In CANoe/CANalyzer Offline Mode, it is possible to start the measurement replaying the data that was logged, say in a .blf file. To configure this, please refer to these questions:

> [How do I play a blf file in CANalyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635704/how-do-i-play-a-blf-file-in-canalzyer)
>
> [Running a Blf file in constant Loop for Emulation using CAPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925321/running-a-blf-file-in-constant-loop-for-emulation-using-capl)

However, replay is done as fast as possible. I remember I read this in a document, but I can't find out where.

**Is there a way to slow down the replay speed of .blf (or any) log file and what is it?**

Or, conversely, does anybody have the reference to documentation where they state this can't be done? I have the feeling that this replay speed is impacting on some scripts I'm developing, since my PC can't be "as fast as possible".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you state, per-default CANoe reads and replays the data as fast as possible in offline mode.

However, you can set an `AnimationDelay` which will slow down the replay. The value has to be set in the CAN.ini file. After setting the value you do not start the replay by clicking "Start" but rather by clicking "Animate" (a lightning bolt next to a sheet of paper).

You can search the CANoe docu for *Animate* for more details.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. The search function on my CANoe is not working very well, because I can find very little information regarding this mode. One thing that is bugging me out is that the programmable nodes with key/actions mapped are not working. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: Offline mode is really offline. The only source of data and events is coming from log-files, i.e. no timers, no keyboard events, no panel, etc. Maybe you are more looking for Online mode but without attached hardware? I.e. you replace the "real nodes" in the simulation setup by replay nodes. Is that more suitable for your use case?